# Storing extended IIdentity in HttpContext.Current.User (IPrinciple)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created an `ExtendedId` class which extends `GenericIdentity`.  (This stores Id as well as name)

In a httpmodule I stored this extended id in Current.User like so:

```
HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(myExtendedId, roles);
```

Problem is, later, how do I get at my `ExtendedId` type again?

If I try this:

```
ExtendedId eId = (ExtendedId)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
```

I get a casting error.  I have a feeling I'm doing something stupid here with casting, but I'm a bit foggy this morning.

Answer (score 2):

try

ExtendedId eId = (ExtendedId )((GenericPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User).Identity;

or

ExtendedId eId = ((GenericPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User).Identity as ExtendedId;

Comment: Thanks for your help, turned out to be something else in the end (see my post).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this turned out to be a silly error. The cast to ExtendedId was failing in cases where HttpContext.Current.User.Identity had not yet been set to ExtendedId (was GenericIdentity as standard). I added a type check to prevent this. Sorry for wasting people's time!